# Entity Framework startup time slow against SQL DB on Azure

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having an issue, and I am not sure where to start. I have a Windows Forms application which utilizes EF 6 database-first. Now when starting the application with a database served locally on the same machine, the application starts up in around 5 seconds. But with the same database on Azure, the application takes up to 40 / 50 seconds to start up.

The database is hosted in Europe and I looked at the scaling - none of the resources are utilized 100% when starting up the application.

I am really struggling to find an idea where to start looking - but this is really a problem. I tend to think, that when migrating from Azure D (Germany hosted Azure) to global Azure, the problem got much worse - but I have been procrastinating the problem, so I cannot tell.

Do you guys have any hints on where to look into?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a 10 DTU database by any chance? The barebones developer level one?

Comment: Standard S2: 50 DTUs - but I looked into the DTU contingent, and it hardly scratches the surface.

Comment: Where/how is the web application or client applications deployed?

Comment: The application runs on a terminal server in our data center which is located in Germany. The startup time seems to depend slightly on the machine the application is running on - we could see some difference between different virtual machines, but what staggers me is the difference between local db and azure DB, which leads to a startup time factor around 20

Comment: Does the speed get any better if you access the server via Azure Data Studio or SSMS? If its fairly quick (it should be at 50 DTUs, S2) - it's probably worth posting the code used at startup etc. Are you applying migrations or anything on launch?

Comment: Is the question, if SSMS opens the DB more quickly? Yes - working with SSMS is slighty more laggy than working locally, but not in dimensions of 40+ seconds.

Comment: Did you profile the app to see where the startup time is spent? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. Turns out, there was a second connection string that I did not see. So the application tried to connect to an non-existing database until it got a timeout. When fixing this, the applications startsup like a breeze!

Don't know, why I did not find that out, while debugging. Thanks for you help!